# Angluar app gets stuck when gesturing back on Safari

Tags: ios, angular, macos, safari

I am developing an angular 10 app and on safari when I use the back gesture (on a desktop touchpad the gesture with 2 fingers) my app gets stuck (I can't scroll down or click anything) for a while even if it receives data from the backend. If I use the browser's back button it works fine, it also works fine if I use another browser.

Here is a sample of my code:

Html:

```
<div class="container-md">
  <div *ngFor="let item of items.content">
    <a routerLink="{{item.id}}">
      <div style="height: 400px">{{item.title}}</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ts:

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  items: Page<Item>;
  constructor(private service: ItemService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.findAll().subscribe(p => this.items = p)
  }
}
```

How can I fix the issue of Safari for the back gesture?

Thanks,